# Получение переменной из глобального окружения Windows

Tags: windows, bat, virtualenv, path

Имеется среда разработки, которая умеет выполнять prebuild скрипты. Проблема в том, что для сборки создается свое окружение и команда, которая в винде работает, так как ее путь прописан в переменную окружения Path, в скрипте при сборке выдает ошибку.
Есть ли возможность в Windows, находясь в другом окружении, вытащить переменную Path из стандартного окружения?

Comment: Эммм... ты хочешь узнать что написано в стандатном %PATH% винды? Я немного не понял вопроса.

Comment: Да, IDE собирает проект под ARM, для чего видимо создает свое окружение,в  котором в переменной Path свое значение. Вопрос как получить переменную Path винды.

Comment: А в настройках (расширенных) самого IDE смотрел?

Comment: Само собой. Вопрос отчасти и теоретический, возможно ли из такого окружения достучаться до системы.

Comment: Ну, первое, что приходит в голову - посмотреть в https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_Explorer какие ключи и прочее будут отображаться при запуске\компиляции в IDE. На несложных прогах вполне помогает.

Comment: Прога - переработанный Eclipse, в диспетчере задач ничего полезного не отображает

Comment: А если запустить бинарник IDE из cmd с ключиком `-h`, `-?`, `--help` или `/?` ? Там будут какие-нить режимы дебага?

Comment: Попробуйте либо глобальные настраивать (они в дополнительных свойствах системы, там же, где PATH), либо через команду ```SET``` в cmd. Вообще тоже немного не понял вопрос